# CakePHP using a table to show relation between two tables

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

So I was building a cake project with a coworker the other day and he used a table in the database (users_credentials) to create a link between two constant tables (users and credentials.) When I tried to duplicate that result with a project I'm working on alone, it isn't working. Can anyone throw me a bone? I just need something to Google or a name or something.

Thanks
Justin

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to connect a user to some credentials? What you can do is give each row an unique number (primary key) and combine those two keys in another table.

You could search google for "foreign keys and primary keys" I think, or search for an ERD (Entity-relationship diagram).

Answer (score 0):

You will likely need to just do a join of the 3 tables. The [CakePHP user guide](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html) offers some help on how to do that assuming you've got your application hooked up to the database correctly. It looks like Cake also does some of the heavy lifting for associating your Models with one another as well [as documented here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html). I'm more familiar with CodeIgniter's syntax, but the basic idea is the same:

```
select something from users
join users_credentials on user id
join credentials on credential id
```